# Are logs kept for past at jobs?

Tags: logs, at

I ran a few jobs with `at` command and, if possible, I want to see which commands I ran in what directories. I work with Linux Mint 16 if this is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `at` jobs do not appear in bash_history. Apparently once the jobs are run, they vanish. If you want to keep logs, you can add `echo 'some comment' > ~/at.log` lines manually.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the bash history is useful for you; see the file `.bash_history` in your home directory. To query the bash history, just use the command `history` (see the [bash reference guide, ch. 9.2](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Using-History-Interactively)), together with `grep` if neccesary.

*(Edited - removed content regarding pending `at` jobs).*

Comment: I know how to list with `atq` and see the details of pending jobs. I was asking for completed jobs. I will check .bash_history.

Comment: Sorry, missed that point. I've removed the irrelevant part of my answer.